# Will joining a US visa diversity program affect my future B1 requests?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, italian-citizens

I currently have a B1 visa for 2 years (I am Italian).

I'm not planning to move permanently to the U.S. but wouldn't mind joining the lottery for the diversity program.

B1 Visa is given under the assumptions of non-immigrant intents.
Joining the diversity program would affect my future B1 renewals requests (If I'll ever need to go back again to the U.S. for work)?

Comment: What is the point of joining the lottery if you are not planning to move permanently to the US?

Comment: Why don't you use the visa waiver program instead of a B1 visa?

Comment: Because I was asked by an institution to enter the U.S. under that particular visa.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't automatically affect it negatively, but:

If you are being interviewed for your Visa, you should be prepared to answer questions about the parallel green card lottery; basically, you need to *convincingly* explain your *'dual intent'*; i.e. "you are trying to get the non-permanent visa and would afterwards leave the country as required; but at the same time you would gladly get a green card and immigrate".

See #10 on this government FAQ: https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Diversity-Visa/DV-Instructions-Translations/DV-2017-Instructions-Translations/DV-2017%20Instructions%20and%20FAQs.pdf

There are many discussion about cross-effecting, but no official USCIS statement. Here is one example of a qualified opinion: https://www.quora.com/U-S-Immigration-Does-entering-the-Green-Card-Lottery-Diversity-Visa-worsen-your-chances-of-getting-an-American-visa-in-the-future

Comment: This answer would be better with sources....

Comment: Wasn't one of the questions in the DS-160 that needs to be filled out for applying for a visa if one has ever participated in the diversity program lottery?

Comment: If you "win" the green card lottery, you are now allowed to apply for an immigrant visa. Just participating in the lottery--you have not applied for an immigrant visa yet.

Comment: @Aganju, maybe you should look for that. Last year my nephew got sent to secondary, answered "no" when asked if he'd applied for an immigrant visa before, and got reamed out because the CBP officer said he'd twice entered the diversity lottery. In fact he hadn't (his country of birth was and is excluded), but his father had many years before when he was a minor and he was named on those entries.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: No, however read below:

I am unaware of any formal guidelines on the subject.
I recollect that in previous versions of DS-160 (the form you file when applying for a B-1) there was a question similar to "have you ever applied for immigration benefits/intended to immigrate to the US?". [New DS-160](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/sample-ds-160-form-us-visa-application.pdf) Does not have this question.

There were multiple discussions on [trackitt](http://www.trackitt.com/) regarding the subject. The consensus was that application for a DV lottery does not constitute immigration intent. Reason is that somebody else might have submitted the application for you. There are known cases when applications were submitted en masse without applicant consent (Ukraine). Immigration intent starts with filing something immigration related which 
1. required your signature/physical approval.
2. names you as a beneficiary
E.g. I-140 (not I-130), I-485/ DS-260 and similar.

I know 4 people playing the lottery and having little trouble obtaining B-1 visa.